# PG::Internal error: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1812151518

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, size

We are using rails transaction to update in 3 associated tables.
In this operation 10 insertion and 18 updation and 8 select queries has been running as bulk transaction.
And we are using redis cache server.
That time we are facing the issue as follow

PG::Internal error: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1812151518

we need any suggestions.

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL log to find out whist query causes the error. Look at the query's execution plan.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.